# Rotating word loop animation with Framer motion

Tags: css, reactjs, framer-motion, chakra-ui

I'm not sure what to call it other than rotating word loop, but basically I mean the animation where a word disappears upwards or downwards and another word appears. For an example you can check the [Auth0 website](https://auth0.com/), which is what initially inspired me to want to create this.

I'm really bad at animations, but I'm using Chakra UI, which comes with Framer motion, so I want to use that to create this animation. I have managed to get something working, but it only seems to work properly when the parent container's `display` is set to `inline`, which means there isn't any space between it and the preceding word (unless I add margin of course). It also feels like there should be a better way of doing it than adding `position: absolute`, but everything I've tried hasn't worked. Here is the code:

```js
import {
  Box,
  Center,
  chakra,
  ChakraProvider,
  Heading,
  Text
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import * as React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

const MotionSpan = motion(chakra.span);

interface TextLoopProps {
  texts: string[];
}

const TextLoop: React.FC<TextLoopProps> = ({ texts }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState<number>(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let next = index + 1;
      setIndex(next % texts.length);
    }, 3 * 1000);
  }, [index, setIndex, texts]);

  return (
    <Box display="inline" position="relative" w="100%">
      <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
        <MotionSpan
          position="absolute"
          key={index}
          layout
          variants={{
            enter: {
              translateY: 20,
              opacity: 0,
              height: 0
            },
            center: {
              zIndex: 1,
              translateY: 0,
              opacity: 1,
              height: "auto"
            },
            exit: {
              zIndex: 0,
              translateY: -20,
              opacity: 0,
              height: 0
            }
          }}
          initial="enter"
          animate="center"
          exit="exit"
          transition={{
            translateY: { type: "spring", stiffness: 300, damping: 200 },
            opacity: { duration: 0.5 }
          }}
        >
          {texts[index]}
        </MotionSpan>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </Box>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Center flexDirection="column" h="100vh" w="100vw">
      <Box>
        <Heading>
          <Text as="span">Secure access</Text>
          <br />
          <Text as="span">for </Text>
          <TextLoop texts={["mice", "sheep", "cows"]} />
        </Heading>

        <Heading>
          <Text as="span">But not</Text>{" "}
          <TextLoop texts={["cats", "goats", "bulls"]} />
        </Heading>
      </Box>
    </Center>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and here is a [link to the CodeSandbox I created](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-pine-jxlk0q?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: What is your question? Your example seems to work fine aside from needing some margin or padding like you say. You could also use a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) if you can't use margin or padding for some reason.

Comment: I know it works, but it seems like I just stumbled on a solution and I feel like there should be a better way of doing it

Comment: You just described 90% of my programming projects. 